# Locate where specific font face is being used on webpage?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-chrome-devtools

My webpage loads fonts not in use. "New Times Roman" is being loaded on my front page. I've looked through all the page elements in Chrome DevTool, and searched through the entirety of my stylesheets, but it is nowhere to be found.

Is there any way to find the exact location of where loaded fonts are being used on a page/website?

Comment: This probably means the font you've "imported" or "defined" is not compatible/supported by your browser or has not been imported correctly. Check your console for any errors with importing the font, ensure it is being imported correctly in the `head` if it's a custom font. Also, supply your code & details of your browser

Comment: Try finding out which code loads it: use the network panel in devtools - specifically the `initiator` column when the panel is in the grid view.

Comment: Times New Roman is the typical font that Windows-based browsers will use when no font has been set (as well as when you specify the font should be `serif` rather than some specific font)